# How do I directly boot to a terminal, bypassing X11?

Tags: xorg, command-line, gdm

I am seeking a help regarding the following issues:

1. How to turn off the *X server*  when I have already logged into Ubuntu
   (I know about `startx` to start the *X server* but don't know how to shut it down).
2. When I start my machine, *Ubuntu* directly boots automatically *X*.
   What I need to do if I want to boot to plane terminal instead of *X*?
   (after that I can use `startx` to start the *X* if I feel so).